# Detect when user leaves window

Tags: angularjs

I want to detect when user exit window with `AngularJS`. My app doesn't use `ngRoute`. So, I can't use `$destroy` or `$locationChangeStart`.

Can you help me ?

Comment: How about `window`'s `onBeforeUnload` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$locationChangeStart](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location):

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function( event ) {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
    if (!answer) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Or use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
  if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
    event = window.event;
  }
  if (event) {
    event.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
}
```